# Snowflake JavaScript SP does not support all methods described in official documentation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a JavaScript stored procedure in Snowflake that performs an `INSERT INTO` statement. As a result I would like to receive the amount of rows that have been inserted into the target table. The Snowflake documentation describes that I should be able to achieve this by applying the method `getNumRowsInserted()` to the object `Statement`. Yet it does not seem to work at all.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE my_little_test (x INT, y INT);

INSERT INTO my_little_test
SELECT 1,2;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_test_sp()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

var result          = {"num_rows":""};

var stmt            = "INSERT INTO my_little_test SELECT 3, 4";

var exec_stmt       = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:stmt}).execute();

result["num_rows"] = exec_stmt.getNumRowsInserted();
        
return result;

$$
;

CALL merge_test_sp();
```

It throws this error message:

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught TypeError: exec_stmt.getNumRowsInserted is not a function in MERGE_TEST_SP at 'result["num_rows"] = exec_stmt.getNumRowsInserted();' position 31 stackstrace: MERGE_TEST_SP line: 9
```

However applying the method `getNumRowsAffected` works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE my_little_test (x INT, y INT);

INSERT INTO my_little_test
SELECT 1,2;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_test_sp()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

var result          = {"num_rows":""};

var stmt            = "INSERT INTO my_little_test SELECT 3, 4";

var exec_stmt       = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:stmt}).execute();

// this method somehow works ?!

result["num_rows"] = exec_stmt.getNumRowsAffected();
        
return result;

$$
;

CALL merge_test_sp();
```

The output is `{"num_rows": 1}`.

Also other methods do not work as I tried the same thing with `MERGE INTO` statements. `getNumDuplicateRowsUpdated`, `getNumRowsDeleted`, `getNumRowsUpdated` all of them do not work. Only the less informative method `getNumRowsAffected()` works.

Has anyone experienced the same issue? Does someone know a work-around for this?

BTW: Heres the link to the documentation I am refering to: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#object-statement

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE my_little_test (x INT, y INT);

INSERT INTO my_little_test
SELECT 1,2;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_test_sp()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var result          = {"num_rows":""};
var stmt            = "INSERT INTO my_little_test SELECT 3, 4";
var exec_stmt       = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:stmt});

exec_stmt.execute();
result["num_rows"] = exec_stmt.getNumRowsInserted();
return result;
$$
;

CALL merge_test_sp();
```

You assign a resultset to exec_stmt by running snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:stmt}).execute(), this is why it doesn't have getNumRowsInserted method is not available.

Comment: Hey Gokhan, thx this works. But why is it different for getNumRowsAffected?

Comment: because getNumRowsAffected is also a method defined in resultset.

Comment: Hey Gokhan, ok makes sense. Thank you :)